# CodeIgniter attaching xls/xlsx to email delivers --B_ATC_#-- only

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, email

I have a form which alone emails out just fine. If I upload an image, it emails out after attaching the image just fine. But if the uploaded file is an xls or xlsx then the received email is just a single line --B_ATC_565ddfb61a799--.
No form data. No attachments. Happens whether I attach the file as I begin to create the html email or just before sending.

I am using CodeIgniter for the form, upload, and email. The form data and uploaded filenames are saved to a db and then looped thru to attach files.

The file itself is fine when I ftp it from the server after upload.
I am using the full path from the root.
I have tried multiple files, all with the same result. If an xls/xlsx file is one of the attachments, it fails.

Any and all suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With further testing I discovered it would fail if there was anything attached. It also failed when I tried to turn the attachments into links.

It turned out to be a path problem. I had changed a constant name and missed changing it in that statement.

Hate it when I cause my own confusion, but it never fails seems I figure it out right after I ask the question.